# Is my question now in an acceptable form for the site?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

My [most recent question was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65164220/do-not-understand-the-solution-for-the-binary-tree-maximum-path-sum-problem) because it was not focused. I have edited it to make it more focused and voted to reopen it.
Do you think the question is now good enough for the site or is it still not good enough to be reopened?

Comment: Hmm.  Wasn't seeing a problem with [the original](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65164220/1), either.  Explaining broad swathes of code is broad.  Explaining a *narrow* bit of code isn't, and I'm not seeing you ask for a whole lot here.

Comment: @Makoto I think the original revision asking for "be solved differently" can trigger broadiness...

Comment: Your original question was bordering on being too broad. You appeared to be asking for an explanation of the entire code, as well as looking for alternative solutions. I may not have voted to close it, but I can understand users doing that. Your edit focuses the question to only ask why a specific variable is returned in the recursive call, as opposed to some other variable. I think your question is on-topic now.

Comment: @AndrewT.:  In the ~70 seconds in which I read the question, I understood that the ask was about the explanation on the site and why it made sense, or if there was an alternative to the solution posted.  Neither of these asks are broad, but they do require some kind of time investment to establish this.  My gut tells me that many people didn't wanna take that time to establish that, so they went with "close it" instead.

Comment: Typicall questions on SO are about non-working code. When you don't understand something in working code, it's ok to ask question about it. But it has to be very *specific* question. Dumping the big amount of code, which require background knowledge is not good. Unfortunately I am not a java expert, but I am sure the question can be formulated more specifically and require only few lines of code and no irrelevant tags. Then you are likely to get an answer or rather a duplicate link.

Comment: @Sinatr _Unfortunately I am not a java expert, but I am sure the question can be formulated more specifically and require only few lines of code and no irrelevant tags._ My original question was about the algorithm and the reasoning behind it. It had little to do with Java. The comments for that question did a good job at clarifying my confusion but I changed my question because I did not want it to be closed.

Comment: @Sinatr Moreover, I am getting mixed signals from the people who have responded to this meta post. Some are saying the question is good now and some are saying it was good before and I have made it worse now. So I am not too sure what is necessary. I shall probably follow Bergi's advice and put back the details of my original question (while excluding the part asking about alternate solutions)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your original question text (before all the edits) was just fine. You explained your understanding of what the code does, you asked a particular question ("*why this variable not the others?*"), and you quoted the course's explanation for that which you couldn't understand.

The only thing that is too broad is "*Can this problem be solved differently?*", which doesn't really fit into your core question and possibly has many answers.

So I'd suggest

> I am confused about the reasoning behind these lines of code:
>
> ```
> int max_single = Math.max(Math.max(l, r) + node.data, node.data);
> int max_top = Math.max(max_single, l + r + node.data);
> res.val = Math.max(res.val, max_top);
> return max_single;
> ```
>
> I believe the code above follows this logic but I do not understand
> **WHY this logic is correct or valid**:
>
> > For each node there can be four ways that the max path goes through
> > the node:
> >
> > 1. Node only
> > 2. Max path through Left Child + Node
> > 3. Max path through Right Child + Node
> > 4. Max path through Left Child + Node + Max path through Right Child
>
> <s>Moreover</s>*In particular*, I do not understand why `max_single`
> is being returned in the function `findMaxUtil` when we the variable
> `res.val` contains the answer we are interested in. The following
> reason is given on the website but I do not understand it:
>
> > An important thing to note is, root of every subtree need to return
> > maximum path sum such that at most one child of root is involved.
>
> Could someone provide an explanation for this <s>solution</s>*part*?
> <s>Can this problem be solved differently?</s>

Comment: I followed your suggestion and updated my question :)

Answer (score 22):

I've actually seen the question the first time when you posted it. I didn't vote to close but I understand the reasons why one would:

In the initial state the question had two main points:

- How does this algorithm work?
- Why only this specific variable is returned?

The issues:

- Two questions at once, even though both can be answered at once as well.
- You didn't really put into words *what* you don't understand about the algorithm.

It's pretty much equivalent to someone asking: "Hey, there is Quicksort. How does it work?". Please notice that this is only an example. Someone could explain the algorithm for you but that's not really the intention behind Stack Overflow. You need to express *what* you don't understand about the algorithm, not just that you don't understand it. An answerer is supposed to address something specific about the algorithm (focused Q&A), not the whole algorithm itself.

I think in your specific case, it's opinion-based to close-vote it, but it has its reasons. Also keep in mind that SO is community-driven, people have different opinions.

Now with your recent edits you've focused the question but sadly removed some parts that gave us more context about your current understanding, namely in Revision 2.

An answerer still has to explain the algorithm to you. You are asking why one specific variable is returned, which is an essential part of the algorithm. Ask yourself this:

*If I ask why one specific variable X is returned but not Y, why *should* Y be returned in my current understanding?*

This is *exactly* what you've removed and should include again. This is something that an answerer can address and clarify for you.

Comment: Why answering here and not there if question is fine?

Comment: @Sinatr This is not an answer to the question, it's a discussion about the question

Comment: @Bergi, it seems to me the question is not yet answerable. OP is asking: "Why is X and NOT any of the other variables being returned by the function in each recursive call?" To me it sounds like OP: 1) doesn't understand algorithm 2) doesn't understand what method does 3) doesn't understand what is return value 4) thinks something different about it 5) maybe don't understand basics (what are local variable, reference types, assigning property of instance passed as parameter, etc.). You have options: either take a risk and post answer (bad idea) or vote close as too broad/require clarification.

Comment: @Bergi, and specifically about my comment, this answer is from java-expert and I am not the one. The easy proof I am wrong would be his answer there. But there is none.

Comment: @Sinatr This sounds very much like an answer to this meta question. You should tell the OP why you think it's still bad and how to improve it. But I think I now understand what your original comment meant to say: "*If you think it's a good question now, can you please answer it to show me how it is answerable, I still couldn't.*"?

Comment: @Bergi, I'd post one if I would be *sure*. I am not. The upvotes here prove I am wrong. The missing answers there prove I am right. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164800/1997232) doesn't looks as a good one (it's maybe a correct one, but the thing is - we don't know what OP problem exactly is).

Comment: @akuzminykh, if you think it's a good question now, can you please answer it to show me how it is answerable, I still couldn't.

Comment: That said, I have to agree with @Sinatr. The OP removing the part about his understanding actually made the question worse. It should not have been reopened yet imo. (-1).

Comment: @Sinatr Good points. I'm just not sure why the question being open should go hand-in-hand with me answering it.

Comment: @Sinatr _This answer doesn't looks as a good one (it's maybe a correct one, but the thing is - we don't know what OP problem exactly is)._ Bergi hit the nail on its head with his answer. His modified version of my question was my actual question.

Comment: Actually, I think questions about algorithms should be on Software Engineering Stack Exchange.

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy Rather [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @akuzminykh Oh, yes, I had forgotten that SE network. Thanks for the advice!